# Error when push files to heroku (error: failed to push some refs to ...)

Tags: python, django, git, heroku, pycharm

When I try to type "git push heroku master" in the console, I have the following problem. This is my second approach to heroku and again I have a problem in the same place, I was looking for advice on the Internet, but nothing helps me

```
(venv) C:\Users\patryk\Desktop\Django\MyPage>git push heroku master
Enumerating objects: 33, done.
Counting objects: 100% (33/33), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (27/27), done.
Writing objects: 100% (33/33), 17.14 KiB | 1.90 MiB/s, done.
Total 33 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote:  !     Python has released a security update! Please consider 
upgrading to python-3.7.3
remote:        Learn More: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python- 
runtimes
remote: -----> Installing python-3.7.4
remote: -----> Installing pip
remote: -----> Installing SQLite3
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to xxx.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/xxx.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/xxx.git'
```

requirements.txt file:

```
-r requirements-dev.txt
gunicorn
psycopg2
```

requirements-dev.txt file:

```
dj-database-url==0.5.0
dj-static==0.0.6
Django==2.2.4
django-bootstrap-form==3.4
djangorestframework==3.10.2
Pillow==6.1.0
python-decouple==3.1
pytz==2019.2
sqlparse==0.3.0
static3==0.7.0
```

Comment: Hello @pkucinski! It seems that the problem is not with git itself, but actually with the initialization of the project. Heroku (the remote repository) rejects the push because your app fails to compile.

Let me see if I got it right: the first line of your "requirements.txt" file is "-r requirements-dev.txt"? If so, you should remove it, because Python will fail parsing it.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it still doesn't work :/

Comment: might be an issue with Pillow installation if you are pip installing `*dev.txt`. make sure you installed  `libjpeg-dev zlib1g-dev` before running  pip install requirements.